# Not able to find .sfdx path to delete the user name in MAC

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

From my visual studio code I authorized my org some three months before. So the user name and token will be stored in alias.json file in the .sfdx folder. Not my org password got changed. So when I tried to re authorize the org it is still considering the old password.

In windows machine also I come across the same issue so what i will do is, I will go to the user /.sfdx path and will delete the json file which will be stored as org user name

The same thing I tried in MAC like sudo ~/.sfdx but I am getting

```
sudo: /Users/hithesh/.sfdx: command not found
```

so not sure how to go to that folder and find all the JSON files insode that folder

Comment: Why would you want to do `sudo ~/.sfdx`? (This attempts to run `.sfdx` as the user root - surely not what you want!) If you're looking for how to remove a file from the CLI, it is some thing like `rm ~/.sfdx/alias.json` - if this is the file you want to delete - but why would you want to do this? The file does not just contain the org with the changed password - have a look! Can you not simply do `SFDX: Authorize an Org` in VSCode? Maybe after `SFDX: Log out from Default Org`?

Comment: @FelixvanHove even if i give Authorize an org with new paswword I am always getting token expired. So have to delete the JSON file insode .sfdx which was created with old password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **remove an old hub org**, or non-scratch org from Salesforce DX org list, you need to manually cleanup the DX configs in the local installation. It would be nice for this to be something in the actual CLI commands: the ability to clean up old orgs that are no longer needed. For the time being, use the following steps:

On **Mac OS and Linux**, you can find your DX config folder, called .sfdx, in your user home directory.

```
cd ~/.sfdx
```

On **Windows**, you can use

```
%USERPROFILE%\.sfdx
```

In that folder there are a host of .json files, named for the username of the admin user you registered for that org.

Source: https://matheus.dev/salesforce-dx-useful-cli-commands/

Comment: This resolved my issue . Thanks